# How to chage redirect route after email verification in Laravel7?

Tags: laravel

I have email verification url as below created by laravel email verify route.

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/email/verify
```

After email verified, then I call this url again. It redirect to home route as below url.

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/home
```

But I would like to redirect to specific route instead. Any advice or guidance to override somewhere on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can modify the redirect `URL` after the email has been verified by the end-user, by setting the `redirectTo` property in the `VerificationController`, as stated in the official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/verification#after-verifying-emails):

> After an email address is verified, the user will automatically be redirected to /home. You can customize the post verification redirect location by defining a redirectTo method or property on the VerificationController.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Comment: Dear Stefano A., That's work for single fixed route. In my case I have multiple target route separated by user. So override method is need instead.

Comment: The redirectTo can also be a method, which can be overwritten to handle your specific scenario

Answer (score 0):

I have solution by override `show` method and also `user()->hasVerifiedEmail();`

```
public function show(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail() == 1){
        ....
```

if verified then redirect to target route else redirect to `view('auth.verify');`